# Use of the word "entire"

Tags: grammar

Why should I use the words "entire group of boys" instead of "entire boys". I know the first one is correct but can't explain why other than it sounds right. I need to explain why as part of a paper.

Comment: Maybe because "entire boys" sounds like the boys' whole bodies instead of parts of boys?  "Entire" defines the group, not the boys, IMO.

Comment: Another option is "the entirety of the boys." But to me that's kind of awkward and sounds like a PE teacher from the 1970s. And it's not a phrase I would use, without boys/boy's/boys' being a modifier, such as in "the entirety of the boys team." But then you could just say "the entire boys team." But "the entirety of the boys group" seems to have a different stress from "the entire group of boys."

Comment: It's just that the construction ***the entire X***, and synonymous alternatives such as *the **complete** X, the **whole** X*, syntactically and logically require a ***singular X***. That's to say it can't always directly replace ***all of the X***, within which ***X*** can be either singular or plural.

Answer (score 2):

*Entire* means *whole*, *all parts of*.

Now, *the entire group (of boys)* means the whole group (as opposed to a part of the group), whereas *entire boys* means whole boys (as opposed to parts of boys — arms, legs, heads).

> The entire car -> the whole car, tires, seats, engine, etc
>   The entire group of cars -> the whole group, every single car in the group